# Checkbox value totaler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wanting to have a group of checkboxes and when they are selected it will add the price to a total field but if there are 2 certain ones checked then the price will need to be different
e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Options[]" title="20"id="Options[]" value="Option 1" /> Option 1 <input type="checkbox" name="Options[]" title="5" id="Options[]2" value="Option 2" /> Option 2 <input type="checkbox" name="Options[]" title="10" id="Options[]3" value="Option 3" /> Option 3
```

But if Option 2 and 3 are selected then total field should show $12, as in apply a discount

Thanks

Comment: can you share the html for the checkboxes also

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wku7sg9j/1/

Comment: Why $10 + $5 = $12 ? I cant follow u

Comment: A "discount" would be applied so that it became $12